# Adding Dropdown List

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2A3D5A;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #69788C;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 20%;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #4F76B1;
  color: white;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background: #4F76B1;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

How to add a dropdown list that contains link 1, link 2 and link 3 when hovering the News tab.

I found many examples on the internet, but I couldn't just add it to this code instead I had to rewrite this code. Can you suggest a simple enhancement to this existing code to do the extra function.

Comment: use a <div> to wrap around the News <a> Tag, from there you can use css :hover to display/hide the submenu.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? It should be fairly self-explanatory but drop me a comment if not and I'll explain.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #2A3D5A;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #69788C;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 20%;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #4F76B1;
  color: white;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background: #4F76B1;
  color: white;
}

#news {
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

#news:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}

.menuitem {
  padding-block: 0.125rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news" id='news'>News
    <div class='menu'>
      <div class='menuitem'>Link1</div>
      <div class='menuitem'>Link2</div>
      <div class='menuitem'>Link3</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```